# Create multiple Tabs with Next/Previous buttons in multiple pop up Modals

Tags: javascript, html, css, tabs

I am working on a knowledge bank on a single HTML page.
The idea is that I have 8 pop-up modals, each modal will have it own steps.
The steps will be created with tabs and I want to add `next/previous` buttons to each tab on each modal.

Right now, I have 8 `pop-up modals`. I have added the tabs with buttons on all tabs in all modals. I am struggling with the following issue: When I open the first modal and click next/previous, it works but it works on all modals. So in the first modal, I click next 10 times, then I close the first modal and I end up in modal 3 on step 4.. What I want is for each `modal/tab` to have its own next and previous modal, instead of one global `previous/next` button that works on all tabs and only works in one modal.

Also, sometimes the modal pop ups don't work.. I have to click multiple times before it opens and sometimes it opens at once..

I am stuck on this problem for a few days now. I think it has something to do with the `JS`. Can someone help me? I would really appreciate it.. I have looked everywhere on the internet for the solution, but there isn't any..

Here is the code:

```js
// Pop Ups JS
// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.querySelectorAll("button.modal-button");

// All page modals
var modals = document.querySelectorAll('.modal');

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("close");

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  btn[i].onclick = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    modal = document.querySelector(e.target.getAttribute("href"));
    modal.style.display = "block";
  }
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
  spans[i].onclick = function() {
    for (var index in modals) {
      if (typeof modals[index].style !== 'undefined') modals[index].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target.classList.contains('modal')) {
    for (var index in modals) {
      if (typeof modals[index].style !== 'undefined') modals[index].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}





// Tabs JS
let currentSection = 0;
let sections = document.querySelectorAll(".section");
let sectionButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".nav > li");
let nextButton = document.querySelector(".next");
let previousButton = document.querySelector(".previous");
for (let i = 0; i < sectionButtons.length; i++) {
  sectionButtons[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    sections[currentSection].classList.remove("active");
    sectionButtons[currentSection].classList.remove("active");
    sections[currentSection = i].classList.add("active");
    sectionButtons[currentSection].classList.add("active");
    if (i === 0) {
      if (previousButton.className.split(" ").indexOf("disable") < 0) {
        previousButton.classList.add("disable");
      }
    } else {
      if (previousButton.className.split(" ").indexOf("disable") >= 0) {
        previousButton.classList.remove("disable");
      }
    }
    if (i === sectionButtons.length - 1) {
      if (nextButton.className.split(" ").indexOf("disable") < 0) {
        nextButton.classList.add("disable");
      }
    } else {
      if (nextButton.className.split(" ").indexOf("disable") >= 0) {
        nextButton.classList.remove("disable");
      }
    }
  });
}

nextButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (currentSection < sectionButtons.length - 1) {
    sectionButtons[currentSection + 1].click();
  }
});

previousButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (currentSection > 0) {
    sectionButtons[currentSection - 1].click();
  }
});
```

```css
/*==================== MODAL CSS ====================*/

body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.button {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* The Modal (background) */

.modal {
  display: none;
  /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;
  /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 100%;
  /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;
  /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/ opacity */
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
  /* Fade in the background */
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: fadeIn;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}


/* Modal Content */

.modal-content {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #3b6e88;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-animation-name: slideIn;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: slideIn;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}


/* The Close Button */

.close {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  font-size: 75px;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-right: 27px;
  ;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #3b6e88;
  color: white;
}

.modal-body {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #3b6e88;
  color: white;
}

.modal-footer {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #3b6e88;
  color: white;
}


/* Add Animation 
        @-webkit-keyframes slideIn {
          from {bottom: -300px; opacity: 0} 
          to {bottom: 0; opacity: 1}
        }
        
        @keyframes slideIn {
          from {bottom: -300px; opacity: 0}
          to {bottom: 0; opacity: 1}
        }
        
        @-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
          from {opacity: 0} 
          to {opacity: 1}
        }
        
        @keyframes fadeIn {
          from {opacity: 0} 
          to {opacity: 1}
        }*/


/*================= TAB CSS=============== */

.section {
  display: none;
}

.section.active {
  display: block;
}

.invisible {
  display: none;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

ul li {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  margin-left: 6px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: .5;
  color: #3b6e88;
  font-size: 17px;
}

ul li.active {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

.next,
.previous {
  padding: 15px 10px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  background: deepskyblue;
  color: white;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
}

.next.disable,
.previous.disable {
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<!-- MODAL BUTTONS -->
<section>
  <div>

    <div>

      <!-- Modal 1 -->
      <button href="#myModal1" class="modal-button">
                    <p>Modal 1</p>
                </button>

      <!-- Modal 2 -->
      <button href="#myModal2" class="modal-button">
                    <p>Modal 2</p>
                </button>

      <!-- Modal 3 -->
      <button href="#myModal3" class="modal-button">
                    <p>Modal 3</p>
                </button>

      <!-- Modal 4 -->
      <button href="#myModal4" class="modal-button">
                    <p>Modal 4</p>
                </button>

      <!-- Modal 5 -->
      <button href="#myModal5" class="modal-button">
                    <p>Modal 5</p>
                </button>

      <!-- Modal 6 -->
      <button href="#myModal6" class="modal-button">
                    <p>Modal 6</p>
                </button>

      <!-- Modal 7 -->
      <button href="#myModal7" class="modal-button">
                    <p>Modal 7</p>
                </button>

      <!-- Modal 8 -->
      <button href="#myModal8" class="modal-button">
                    <p>Modal 8</p>
                </button>

    </div>

  </div>
</section>



<!-- MODALS POP UPS HTML -->
<!-- Modal 1 -->
<div id="myModal1" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">

    <!-- Modal Header -->
    <div class="modal-header">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="active" data-cont="r1">Step 1: Test</li>
        <li data-cont="r2">Step 2: Test</li>
        <li data-cont="r3">Step 3: Test</li>
      </ul>

      <!-- Prev/Next Buttons -->
      <button class="previous disable" data-id="previous">Previous</button>
      <button class="next" data-id="next">Next</button>

      <!-- Close Modal -->
      <span class="close">×</span>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal Body -->
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p> Modal 1</p>
      <!-- Step 1-->
      <section data-id="r1" class="section section-one active">
        <p>Section 1 </p>
      </section>

      <!-- Step 2 -->
      <section data-id="r2" class="section section-two">
        <h2>Section 2</h2>
      </section>

      <!-- Step 3 -->
      <section data-id="r3" class="section section-three">
        <h2>Section 3</h2>
      </section>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal 2 -->
<div id="myModal2" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">

    <!-- Modal Header -->
    <div class="modal-header">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="active" data-cont="r1">Step 1: Test</li>
        <li data-cont="r2">Step 2: Test</li>
        <li data-cont="r3">Step 3: Test</li>
      </ul>

      <!-- Prev/Next Buttons -->
      <button class="previous disable" data-id="previous">Previous</button>
      <button class="next" data-id="next">Next</button>

      <!-- Close Modal -->
      <span class="close">×</span>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal Body -->
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p> Modal 2</p>

      <!-- Step 1-->
      <section data-id="r1" class="section section-one active">
        <p>Section 1 </p>
      </section>

      <!-- Step 2 -->
      <section data-id="r2" class="section section-two">
        <h2>Section 2</h2>
      </section>

      <!-- Step 3 -->
      <section data-id="r3" class="section section-three">
        <h2>Section 3</h2>
      </section>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal 3 -->
<div id="myModal3" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">

    <!-- Modal Header -->
    <div class="modal-header">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="active" data-cont="r1">Step 1: Test</li>
        <li data-cont="r2">Step 2: Test</li>
        <li data-cont="r3">Step 3: Test</li>
      </ul>

      <!-- Prev/Next Buttons -->
      <button class="previous disable" data-id="previous">Previous</button>
      <button class="next" data-id="next">Next</button>

      <!-- Close Modal -->
      <span class="close">×</span>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal Body -->
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p> Modal 3</p>

      <!-- Step 1-->
      <section data-id="r1" class="section section-one active">
        <p>Section 1 </p>
      </section>

      <!-- Step 2 -->
      <section data-id="r2" class="section section-two">
        <h2>Section 2</h2>
      </section>

      <!-- Step 3 -->
      <section data-id="r3" class="section section-three">
        <h2>Section 3</h2>
      </section>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal 4 -->
<div id="myModal4" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">

    <!-- Modal Header -->
    <div class="modal-header">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="active" data-cont="r1">Step 1: Test</li>
        <li data-cont="r2">Step 2: Test</li>
        <li data-cont="r3">Step 3: Test</li>
      </ul>

      <!-- Prev/Next Buttons -->
      <button class="previous disable" data-id="previous">Previous</button>
      <button class="next" data-id="next">Next</button>

      <!-- Close Modal -->
      <span class="close">×</span>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal Body -->
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p> Modal 4</p>

      <!-- Step 1-->
      <section data-id="r1" class="section section-one active">
        <p>Section 1 </p>
      </section>

      <!-- Step 2 -->
      <section data-id="r2" class="section section-two">
        <h2>Section 2</h2>
      </section>

      <!-- Step 3 -->
      <section data-id="r3" class="section section-three">
        <h2>Section 3</h2>
      </section>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal 5 -->
<div id="myModal5" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">

    <!-- Modal Header -->
    <div class="modal-header">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="active" data-cont="r1">Step 1: Test</li>
        <li data-cont="r2">Step 2: Test</li>
        <li data-cont="r3">Step 3: Test</li>
      </ul>

      <!-- Prev/Next Buttons -->
      <button class="previous disable" data-id="previous">Previous</button>
      <button class="next" data-id="next">Next</button>

      <!-- Close Modal -->
      <span class="close">×</span>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal Body -->
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p> Modal 5</p>

      <!-- Step 1-->
      <section data-id="r1" class="section section-one active">
        <p>Section 1 </p>
      </section>

      <!-- Step 2 -->
      <section data-id="r2" class="section section-two">
        <h2>Section 2</h2>
      </section>

      <!-- Step 3 -->
      <section data-id="r3" class="section section-three">
        <h2>Section 3</h2>
      </section>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal 6 -->
<div id="myModal6" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">

    <!-- Modal Header -->
    <div class="modal-header">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="active" data-cont="r1">Step 1: Test</li>
        <li data-cont="r2">Step 2: Test</li>
        <li data-cont="r3">Step 3: Test</li>
      </ul>

      <!-- Prev/Next Buttons -->
      <button class="previous disable" data-id="previous">Previous</button>
      <button class="next" data-id="next">Next</button>

      <!-- Close Modal -->
      <span class="close">×</span>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal Body -->
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p> Modal 6</p>

      <!-- Step 1-->
      <section data-id="r1" class="section section-one active">
        <p>Section 1 </p>
      </section>

      <!-- Step 2 -->
      <section data-id="r2" class="section section-two">
        <h2>Section 2</h2>
      </section>

      <!-- Step 3 -->
      <section data-id="r3" class="section section-three">
        <h2>Section 3</h2>
      </section>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal 7 -->
<div id="myModal7" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">

    <!-- Modal Header -->
    <div class="modal-header">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="active" data-cont="r1">Step 1: Test</li>
        <li data-cont="r2">Step 2: Test</li>
        <li data-cont="r3">Step 3: Test</li>
      </ul>

      <!-- Prev/Next Buttons -->
      <button class="previous disable" data-id="previous">Previous</button>
      <button class="next" data-id="next">Next</button>

      <!-- Close Modal -->
      <span class="close">×</span>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal Body -->
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p> Modal 7</p>

      <!-- Step 1-->
      <section data-id="r1" class="section section-one active">
        <p>Section 1 </p>
      </section>

      <!-- Step 2 -->
      <section data-id="r2" class="section section-two">
        <h2>Section 2</h2>
      </section>

      <!-- Step 3 -->
      <section data-id="r3" class="section section-three">
        <h2>Section 3</h2>
      </section>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal 8 -->
<div id="myModal8" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">

    <!-- Modal Header -->
    <div class="modal-header">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="active" data-cont="r1">Step 1: Test</li>
        <li data-cont="r2">Step 2: Test</li>
        <li data-cont="r3">Step 3: Test</li>
      </ul>

      <!-- Prev/Next Buttons -->
      <button class="previous disable" data-id="previous">Previous</button>
      <button class="next" data-id="next">Next</button>

      <!-- Close Modal -->
      <span class="close">×</span>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal Body -->
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p> Modal 8</p>

      <!-- Step 1-->
      <section data-id="r1" class="section section-one active">
        <p>Section 1 </p>
      </section>

      <!-- Step 2 -->
      <section data-id="r2" class="section section-two">
        <h2>Section 2</h2>
      </section>

      <!-- Step 3 -->
      <section data-id="r3" class="section section-three">
        <h2>Section 3</h2>
      </section>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you try something like this? Code is not tested, but the concept is next:
On open modal trigger remove all 'active' classes, then add active on first tab:

```
for (var i = 0; i < btn.length; i++) {
  btn[i].onclick = function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      modal = document.querySelector(e.target.getAttribute("href"));
      modal.style.display = "block";

      // Remove all active tabs
      var elems = document.querySelectorAll("#" + e.target.id + ">li.active");
      [].forEach.call(elems, function(el) {
        el.classList.remove("active");
      });
      // Add active on first element
      elems[0].classList.add('active')
  }
}
```

Comment: Just tried it, but it did not fix it..